# Como modificar somente um lado da div?

Tags: html, html5, css3

Olá! estou tentando fazer um efeito de transformar só um lado da div como na imagem a seguir, tentei usando skew porém ele modifica a div inteira, vejam como gostaria que ficasse

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o código abaixo para fazer o efeito, mas terá que ajustar as dimensões do CSS manualmente quando for usar em diferentes tamanhos. É fácil, basta ajustar os `margin-left`, `left`, `width` e `height` das `divs`:

```css
#conteudo{
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   margin-left: 5px;
   width: 636px;
   height: 200px;
   float: left;
}

.box { 
   width: 684px;
   height: 200px;
   border-radius: .5em;
}

.img1 {
   position: absolute;
   left: -47px;
   background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0aEM.jpg) no-repeat right;
}

.img2_conteudo {
   width: 383px;
   border-right: 10px solid #fff;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: inline-block;
   transform: skewX(-20deg);
   margin-left: -76px;
}

.img2 {
   transform: skewX(20deg);
   margin-left: 63px;
   background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Uh7.jpg) no-repeat;
   pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteudo">
   <div class="box img1"></div>
   <div class="img2_conteudo">
       <div class="box img2"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: era exatamente isso meu amigo! obrigado!

Comment: @JulianoSouza Fico contente! Obg!